# Favicon of format PNG doesn't appear on Google search result page

Tags: html, favicon

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://www.website.com/template/img/website/favicon.png?ver=v2.1.31">
```

We changed our 32x32 png favicon to a 48x48 png favicon, because one of our websites reverted back to the default Wordpress favicon and after deploying the change we noticed that the favicon was reverted back to the Wordpress favicon still on the websites we deployed. So I was wondering if there was a fool-proof way of making sure that our favicon appears on the search result page.

One of the answers I got from Googling was that we should change favicon.png to favicon.ico, but the Google documentation tells us it's not necessary. What changes can we do to make it work without changing the file format?

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/favicon-in-search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, keep in mind that Google can take days or weeks before reflecting your icon in its search results. So any change you make needs patience, unfortunately.

However, you can get insights from Google. Visit `https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=www.website.com` , just make sure to replace the `domain` parameter with your own site. There is no evidence that this is what Google is actually using to fill its results pages. But chances are that what this entry point returns is what you can expect in results pages a bit later.

Comment: The old one shows up when I browse to the url. Does that mean it wasn't web crawled yet? How do you make Google crawl your webpage as soon as possible?

Comment: @caesar No, this is not normal. This entry point is supposed to access your icon in real time, not to return a cached icon. You can check for yourself in your web server logs. Maybe you can get more feedback with https://realfavicongenerator.net/favicon_checker (full disclosure: I'm the author of this service). Oh, and you should make sure there is no `favicon.ico` file in your root directory (or make sure this is the right one).

Answer (score 1):

According to me to add a favicon, one should use the .ico image. Otherwise, it might show some issues. Try converting your .png image to .ico by using [this](https://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-ico)  converter.
This will work for sure.

Here's a text from a webpage I searched about the favicon.

A favicon can actually be either a PNG, GIF, or ICO file. However, ICO files are typically used more than others as the file size is smaller and it is supported in all major browsers. PNGs are used more commonly for IOS, Android, and Windows 10 devices.

So according to this .ico is mostly preferred over any other extension of the image. Hence I would recommend you to use .ico extension for the image.

Comment: Do you have any evidences or references for your hunch about the format?

Comment: I know that png format can be used, but otherwise .ico file is mostly suggested to use.
Here is a text from a website, I searched.

A favicon can actually be either a PNG, GIF, or ICO file. However, ICO files are typically used more than others as the file size is smaller and it is supported in all major browsers. PNGs are used more commonly for IOS, Android, and Windows 10 devices.

Comment: ok, if you add the comment into your answer, I will revert my downvote

Comment: Yes surely, i would do that.